# jQuery Resizable with Angular ng-style doesn't work

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I can't get jquery resizable to work with Angular and ng-style.  I understand that I must specify a height and width when I create a resizable element, but as you can see from the below jsfiddle, any ng-style seems to get ignored, and there is no height or width applied.

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <img resizable src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/"
    ng-style="{'width':'400px', 'height':'200px'}"/>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/85my1qbc/3/

If, however, I replace ng-style with style, it works fine (as below)

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <img resizable src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/"
    style="width:400px;height:200px"/>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/go1qak0w/1/

Any idea how I can get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass ngStyle to your directive, and set the css in the directive.

```
app.directive('resizable', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            callback: '&onResize',
            ngStyle : '=ngStyle'
        },
        link: function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {

            elem.css(scope.ngStyle);
            elem.resizable();
            elem.on('resizestop', function (evt, ui) {
                if (scope.callback) { scope.callback(); }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Reason : When the directive resizable compiles, the width and height of element is zero. You can check this by calling elem.css('width') in the resizable directive.

[Check the updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Netdeamon/85my1qbc/9/)

Comment: This is great, thanks.  It works perfectly with ng-style="{'width':'280px', 'height':'180px'}", but I get issues if I do something like ng-style="getLayerStyle(sceneLayer)"

Comment: As long as it the function returns json object, I dont think we did have any issues. I tried to recreate the issue with ngstyle having function, but it worked fine for me. Here is [link to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Netdeamon/85my1qbc/11/)

Answer (score 1):

Usually ng-style value will be scope variable `$scope.myStyle = {'width':'400px', 'height':'200px'}` and you can use the variable in ngStyle

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <img resizable src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" ng-style="myStyle"/>
</div>
```

Ref: [ngStyle](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle)

Comment: That was a typo...if you check the fiddle you will see that I used the correct syntax with the quote mark.  In my actual code I'm using scope variable, but for simplicity I made it inline.  I don't think this should make a difference.  Any ideas?

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference if I use a scope variable or if I write the style inline, right?

Comment: It looks the same as the original...did you make any changes?

Comment: Thanks, but the image doesn't show up when I press run...this matches the behaviour that I'm talking about in my original post.  It's still ignoring ng-style.